# Solution to store specific files not ignored on .gitignore

Tags: git, file, backup

My problem is that I often forget to backup or I need to use some ignored files in other devices, like .env ones, and sometimes it troubles my day because those files should not be commited, but at the same time I need those files updated if for some reason I need to use this repo in another device.

Is there any solution for that when I commit to my repo, some selected files can stored in a clould service like onedrive or google drive?

I tried to use my repos inside a folder that is synced with my clould, but the amount of files not ignored, like venv or node_modules, more hinders than helps me.

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't your `.env` files often be specific to the device you are running your production system on and therefore not be the same as the `.env` file on your development system where you will commit from?

Comment: Aside from what @TheIceBear noted, env files in general should be rebuilt on demand. The only reason to store such files is when building them takes days. If there's useful data that *can't* be rebuilt automatically, *that* data might go in a repository (perhaps a separate one).

Comment: That makes total sense. But sometimes other things are nice to have, but not nice to commit, like IDE configs...
But I got the point! Thanks all for sharing your concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are specifically targeting ignroed files :

you can list the ignored files in your directory using :

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard -i -o
```

You can then use the output of this command to do something with the listed files.

For example, you can create a tgz archive :

```
# create a tgz archive :
git ls-files --exclude-standard -i -o | xargs tar -czf ../myenvfiles.tgz
```

and copy/extract that archive some place else.

Comment: Thanks! This sure will help-me!